# Jlabel with conditions not displayed

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set a string and color on some Jlabels, but the Jlabels are not shown. I have tried several things, but no solution.

I use conditions on jlabels from another method, but in any way, the text will not be displayed.

My IDE is NetBeans.

The problem start at "private void estadoJugadores...".
The program will compile and run, but like I said, the text will not be displayed.

Sorry that the texts are actually in Spanish.

```
public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form login
     */
    public login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panelPrincipal = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        textoJugador = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        selecionJugador = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        ingresoPassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        ingresoUsuario = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        textoPassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        textoUsuario1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        botonIniciar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        botonSalida = new javax.swing.JButton();
        textoJugador1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        textoJugador2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        textoJugador3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        textoJugador4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        fondoPantalla = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panelPrincipal.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        textoJugador.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        textoJugador.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoJugador.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoJugador.setText("Seleccione el jugador ...");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoJugador, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 480, 180, 30));

        selecionJugador.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        selecionJugador.setMaximumRowCount(4);
        selecionJugador.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Jugador 1", "Jugador 2", "Jugador 3", "Jugador 4" }));
        panelPrincipal.add(selecionJugador, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 520, 140, 30));
        panelPrincipal.add(ingresoPassword, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(310, 470, 190, 30));
        panelPrincipal.add(ingresoUsuario, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(310, 420, 190, 30));

        textoPassword.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        textoPassword.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoPassword.setText("Contraseña");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoPassword, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 470, 80, 30));

        textoUsuario1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        textoUsuario1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoUsuario1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoUsuario1.setText("Usuario");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoUsuario1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 420, 80, 30));

        botonIniciar.setText("Iniciar Sesion");
        panelPrincipal.add(botonIniciar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 523, 110, 30));

        botonSalida.setText("Salir del juego");
        panelPrincipal.add(botonSalida, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(460, 520, 120, 30));

        textoJugador1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        textoJugador1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoJugador1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoJugador1.setText("Jugador 1 :");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoJugador1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 30, 100, 30));

        textoJugador2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        textoJugador2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoJugador2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoJugador2.setText("Jugador 2 :");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoJugador2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 60, 100, 30));

        textoJugador3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        textoJugador3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoJugador3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoJugador3.setText("Jugador 3 :");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoJugador3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 90, 100, 30));

        textoJugador4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        textoJugador4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textoJugador4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textoJugador4.setText("Jugador 4 :");
        panelPrincipal.add(textoJugador4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 120, 100, 30));

        fondoPantalla.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Modelo/background_3.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        panelPrincipal.add(fondoPantalla, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 800, 600));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(panelPrincipal)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(panelPrincipal)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void indicadorEstado(){
    int jugador1;   
        jugador1 = 1;
    int jugador2;
        jugador2 = 0;
    int jugador3;
        jugador3 = 0;
    int jugador4;
        jugador4 = 1;
        estadoJugadores(jugador1, jugador2, jugador3, jugador4);
    }
    private void estadoJugadores(int jugador1, int jugador2, int jugador3, int jugador4){        
        estadoJugador1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        estadoJugador2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        estadoJugador3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        estadoJugador4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        panelPrincipal = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();


        estadoJugador1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14));
        estadoJugador1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        if (jugador1 == 1){
            estadoJugador1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            estadoJugador1.setText("Conectado");
        }
        else {
            estadoJugador1.setForeground(Color.RED);
            estadoJugador1.setText("Desconectado");
        }

        panelPrincipal.add(estadoJugador1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 60, 100, 30));

        estadoJugador2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14));
        estadoJugador2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        if (jugador2 == 1){
            estadoJugador2.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            estadoJugador2.setText("Conectado");
        }
        else {
            estadoJugador2.setForeground(Color.RED);
            estadoJugador2.setText("Desconectado");
        }

        panelPrincipal.add(estadoJugador2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 60, 100, 30));

        estadoJugador3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14));
        estadoJugador2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        if (jugador3 == 1){
            estadoJugador3.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            estadoJugador3.setText("Conectado");
        }
        else {
            estadoJugador3.setForeground(Color.RED);
            estadoJugador3.setText("Desconectado");
        } 

        panelPrincipal.add(estadoJugador3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 60, 100, 30));

        estadoJugador4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14));
        estadoJugador2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        if (jugador4 == 1){
            estadoJugador4.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            estadoJugador4.setText("Conectado");
        }
        else {
            estadoJugador4.setForeground(Color.RED);
            estadoJugador4.setText("Desconectado");
        }

        panelPrincipal.add(estadoJugador4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 60, 100, 30));


    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have called the `indicadorEstado()` method somewhere else in your code?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: `new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout()` Uh-oh!  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @iWumbo i called indicadorEstado(), but nothing changes... don`t show anything...

Comment: @AndrewThompson i didn`t know that, sorry :)

Comment: *"..i didn`t know that.."* I don't know whcich of the 3 things I mentioned to you that you did not know, but go back to the first numbered point. Where is that MCVE? I've been waiting to see that before spending too much time on this matter.